# PyQt Dialog Window opened with Pyinstaller executable is 'unfocused'

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyinstaller

I have a weird problem. 
I created a PyQt5 application and created an executable with Pyinstaller. 
This is the command I used:

```
pyinstaller nbfixer_decoupled.spec
```

And this is the nbfixer_decoupled.spec file:

```
 -*- mode: python -*-
import sys
block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['nbfixer_decoupled.py'],
             pathex=['/Users/peterpetocz/Desktop/NBFixer_app'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)

a.datas+=[('./login.properties','./login.properties','DATA'),('./status.properties','./status.properties','DATA'),('./signature.properties','./signature.properties','DATA')]

pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)


# Package the executable file into .app if on OS X
if sys.platform == 'darwin':
  exe = EXE(pyz,
            a.scripts,
            a.binaries,
            a.zipfiles,
            a.datas,
            name='NBFixer',
            debug=False,
            strip=False,
            upx=True,
            runtime_tmpdir=None,
            console=True,
            icon='nbfixer.icns')

if sys.platform == 'darwin':
   app = BUNDLE(exe,
                name='NBFixer.app',
                info_plist={
                  'NSHighResolutionCapable': 'True'
                },
                icon='nbfixer.icns')

coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               name='nbfixer_decoupled')
```

The output in the /dist folder is 2 files:

A unix executable and an .app executable.

When I launch the unix executable, everything works as expected.

When I launch the .app executable I cannot type characters in input fields for example. The focus seems to remain in my Folder window, even if I click in the input fields.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the `console=True` value needed to be changed to `False`.